# django-storages generates incorrect urls to assets in S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I'm experiencing a problem where the URLs to assets stored on a Europe/London S3 bucket  are not being generated correctly. For example:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/static/wagtailadmin/css/normalize.css

Resulting in such errors in the browser:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response  with MIME type application/xml. See  for more details.

and when you try to access the url:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
   <Code>PermanentRedirect</Code>
   <Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message>
   <Endpoint>mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
   <Bucket>mybucket</Bucket>
   <RequestId>4ER2572A129386F7</RequestId>
   <HostId>+l38ZBh/hDscROXzeWdNfldQtcQm1ZPVq4sNZAZKQKwGHLv7MDRW4H0sf0I3pijD1T0j4oSE6E=</HostId>
</Error>
```

The correct url to the file would be *https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/wagtailadmin/css/normalize.css*.

My project uses vanilla settings generated by [django-cookiecutter](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django):

```
# STORAGES
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSTALLED_APPS += ['storages']  # noqa F405
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = env('DJANGO_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = env('DJANGO_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = env('DJANGO_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
_AWS_EXPIRY = 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': f'max-age={_AWS_EXPIRY}, s-maxage={_AWS_EXPIRY}, must-revalidate',
}
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = 'public-read'  # TODO - not sure if this is ideal

# STATIC
# ------------------------

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'config.settings.production.StaticRootS3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_URL = f'https://{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com/static/'

# MEDIA
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage  # noqa E402


class StaticRootS3Boto3Storage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'static'


class MediaRootS3Boto3Storage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = 'media'
    file_overwrite = False


DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'config.settings.production.MediaRootS3Boto3Storage'
MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com/media/'
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by adding

`AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'`

to my settings. Note it appears that `STATIC_URL` is ignored by *django-storages*.